# compilation error accessing to an array property

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have declared this types:

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;

export type HostelId = {
  id: Scalars['String']
}
```

that I use in this function

```
book (hostel: Array<Maybe<HostelId>>) : boolean {
    console.log (hostel.id[])
}
```

but I get this compilation error

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Maybe<HostelId>[]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue you had on your code is that you are accessing the **id** property
on an **Array** Object, not the actual **HostelId** object.

```
export type Maybe<T> = T | null;

export type HostelId = {
  id: String
}


function book (hostel: Array<Maybe<HostelId>>) : boolean {
    hostel.map((h) => {
      // I wrote this if statement in order to suppress the
      // "Object is possibly 'null'." error
      if (h != null && h.id != null){
        console.log(h.id)
      }
    })
}

let x : HostelId = {id: 'asdf'}
book([x])
```

Answer (score 1):

`hostel` is array so you can not use `id` directly

please change

```
book (hostel: Array<Maybe<HostelId>>) : boolean {
    hostel.map(val=>{
      console.log(val.id);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hostel` is Array of Objects type, that why you are getting error. Where as hostel[0] will be of type HostelId. Can you try as below?

```
book (hostel: Array<Maybe<HostelId>>) : boolean {
    console.log (hostel[0].id[])
}
```